# Overloading function for object inside object

Tags: c++, arrays, object, operator-overloading

I've 2 Classes - `Board` built for `n` number and create a board of `Cell` object of size `n*n`

```
class XOBoard {
    private:
        int n;
        Cell **Board;
        Cell empty_cell{};
        bool valid_range(int y, int x, int n) const;
    public: 
    Cell& operator[](list<int> list) {
        int x = list.front(), y = list.back();
        if (!valid_range(y, x, n)) return empty_cell;
        return Board[x][y];
    }
};


class Cell {
private:
    char validate(char in);
public:
    char ch;
    Cell(char ch = '.');
    char getCell() const;
    void setCell(char ch);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, const Cell& cell) {
        output << cell.ch;
        return output;
    }
    Cell& operator=(const char another) {
        ch = validate(another);
        return *this;
    }
    Cell operator=(const Cell& another) {
        Cell empty;     
        if (this != &another) {         
            if (!(ch != '.' && ch != 'X' && ch != 'O')) {                   
                ch = another.ch;                
            }
            else {
                cout << "illegal" << endl;
                return empty;
            }
        }
        return *this;
    }
```

};

The demand is to make this line work: `char c = board1[{1, 2}].getCell(); cout << c << endl;`.

`board1[{1, 2}]` -> this return an `Cell` object, and I want when there is a print or put it into char variable it will go to `getCell()`.

I do not know which operator overloading i should use to do it.

Thanks you.

Comment: You can define a conversion `Cell::operator char()` but I would be very careful if you really want that. It may cause unexpected conversions in other parts of the code (e.g. when passing a `Cell` to a function taking a `char`)

Comment: If you only care about printing it then adding an `operator<<(std::ostream&, const Cell&)` would do the job. What else do you need the conversion to `char` for?

Answer (score 0):

You can overload the index operator to take a structure which has two int members.

```
struct Point
{
    int x, y;
};


class Board
{
    Cell& operator[](Point p)
    {
        // validate
        // return Board[p.x][p.y];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for dave for giveing me the solution.

To override the method `char c = board[{1,2}]` that board is some object, you should use:

```
operator char const() {
    return ch;
}
```